# Defining CheckBox view as a global variable in java file makes the app terminates in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make a CheckBox variable as a global variable because I am going to use it in two different functions but I found that when I take the CheckBox variable outside the scope of my function (make it global), the app terminates.

This is my code before.

```
 private String createOrderSummary(int priceOfOrder) {
    CheckBox checkBoxValue = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    CheckBox checkBox2Value = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
    boolean WhippedCream = checkBoxValue.isChecked();
    boolean chocolate = checkBox2Value.isChecked();

    EditText Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    return "Name: " + Name.getText() +
            "\nAdd whiped cream? "+(WhippedCream) +
            "\nAdd Chocolate? "+(chocolate) +
            "\nQuantity: "+quantity +
            "\nTotal: $"+(priceOfOrder)+
            "\nThank you!";
}
```

This is my code after

```
CheckBox checkBoxValue = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
CheckBox checkBox2Value = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
boolean WhippedCream = checkBoxValue.isChecked();
boolean chocolate = checkBox2Value.isChecked();

private String createOrderSummary(int priceOfOrder) {
    EditText Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
    return "Name: " + Name.getText() +
            "\nAdd whiped cream? "+(WhippedCream) +
            "\nAdd Chocolate? "+(chocolate) +
            "\nQuantity: "+quantity +
            "\nTotal: $"+(priceOfOrder)+
            "\nThank you!";
}
```

It was working without any problems before I move the first four lines outside the scope of the function and make them global.

Answer (score 1):

Move the finfViewById assignment inside onCreate

```
private Checkbox cb;

onCreate(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activiy_name);
   cb = findViewBy...
}
```

You cant have a field of a View and initialize it on the declaration in Android, because the Activity class has access to the findViewById method but the content is only added after the onCreate lifecyvle method

Answer (score 0):

Please check two things below.

1. boolean WhippedCream = checkBoxValue.isChecked();
   WhippedCream <---- It can be a variable name already reserved or reserved.
2. R.id.checkbox and R.id.checkbox2 xml file check

Comment: Before moving the code outside the method scope, the app was running without any problems. There is no errors in the code in terms of what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be inflated when the class object is created. It should be inflated 'in' or 'after' activitiy's onCreate method is called.